# Conditionally filter a sequence

Tags: scala

Suppose I have an `Option[A => Boolean]`, a `List[A]`, and some set of operations I want to perform on a subset of that list. If the option is set, then I want to filter the list first and then apply my operations. If not, then I want to apply it on the whole list. An example:

```
val a : Option[Int => Boolean] = Option((a : Int) => a % 2 == 0)
val b = 1 to 100
```

I can easily do the following:

```
val c = if (a.isDefined) b.filter(a.get) else b
```

However, this involves calling `a.get`; much conditioning leaves me unable to do this! I could alternatively do:

```
val c = b.filter(a.getOrElse(_ => true))
```

This feels better, but now I am stuck with a second (albeit trivial) operation being carried out for every element of my sequence. I could hope that it will be optimised out, but this still feels imperfect.

What I would like is something lacking either flaw. It feels like there should be a nice way to do it - any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to use the normal option handling methods:

```
a.map(b.filter).getOrElse(b)
```

Comment: Yes; for some reason I was failing to see the idea of flipping the situation around. This is very tidy.

Comment: Yet one more reason why the pattern "option.map().getOrElse()" needs to be added to the standard library.  It's always one of the first things I pimp in.

Comment: @DaveGriffith - Indeed.  I have it also, called `fold` (like Scalaz), with syntax `o.map(f).getOrElse(b)` becoming `o.fold(b)(f)`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically same as Rex Kerr's solution, but uses `fold` from Scalaz to make it slightly more concise.

In general, `x.fold(f, g)` ≡ `x.map(f).getOrElse(g)`.

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> a.fold(b.filter, b)
res112: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing a to:

```
val a : Option[Seq[Int] => Seq[Int]] = Option((a : Seq[Int]) => a.filter(_ % 2 == 0))
val b = 1 to 100
val c = a.getOrElse((f:Seq[Int]) => f)(b)
```

(Note I haven't tried the above, but it should give you the idea)

Comment: Ah, this looks good! The idea of flipping the situation around to apply the list to the option rather than the option to the list makes the situation much nicer! Knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the clarity of pattern matching; it is a very direct translation from your prose description into code:

```
val c = a match {
  case Some(f) => b.filter(f)
  case None => b
}
```